# Populating Chessboard pieces to board using javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help i'm trying to populate the chessboard pieces to my chessboard but seem to be stuck. I'm trying to use document.getElementById but it doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

```
 document.getElementById('00') = '<img src="img/whiteKing.png" />'
```

Comment: Surely you're getting an error in the console. You should really search and you'll get so many results.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely read up about Javascript and DOM elements.

Assuming that you have html something like the following...

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td id="00"></td>
       <td id="01"></td>
       <td id="02"></td>
       <td id="03"></td>
       <td id="04"></td>
       <td id="05"></td>
       <td id="06"></td>
       <td id="07"></td>
   </tr>
   <...> ... </...>
</table>
```

You will then need to create a DOM element

```
var whiteKing = document.createElement('img');
```

The `img` tag uses the `src` attribute to determine what image is fetched/displayed. So set it as you would any other JSON attribute.

```
whiteKing.src = "img/whiteKing.png";
```

Then you can append the new element to an existing one (i.e. your 00 cell)

```
document.getElementById("00").append(whiteKing);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, I hope you just want to replace the html

```
document.getElementById('00').innerHTML = '<img src="img/whiteKing.png" />'
```

Comment: What if the `00` element is an image?

Comment: 00 means id, it'll replace the previous html in there. You better use jquery for these things. It's nice and clean. Easy to implement!

Comment: Not sure what that has to do with anything. If it's an image element you don't want to set the `innerHTML`, you want to set the `src` property.